# In "Hail Caesar," how does Mannix figure out who kidnapped Baird Whitlock

Tags: hail-caesar

In "Hail Caesar," Eddie Mannix discovers that The Future were assisted by

> Burt Gurney, who was also the source about Whitlock and Laurence Laurentz.

How does he figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Hobie Doyle gave him the first clue -- look at the extras. You never know what an extra is thinking. They found an extra on the set of the party at Septimius Severus that 'seemed nervous.' The extra was questioned and didn't know much but was able to describe the truck that Baird was taken in. Apparently, Walt was able to track down the owner of the truck. Next thing we know, the cops are showing up at Burt Gurney's home. And of course, Baird himself told how everyone there were communists.